# insert to realm from json without primary key

Tags: android, realm, realm-java

I have a big JSONArray like this

```
 [{
     "serverId":1,"title":"title!"
 },....]
```

and I have an object:

```
 class A extends RealmObject{
    @PrimaryKey
    public int local_id;

    public int serverId;

    public String title;

 }
```

and I want to add JSON to the realm like this:

```
 realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(A.class,JSONarray);
```

but as you can see there is no local_id in JSON and realm cannot add JSON without PrimaryKey, So is there a way to add my JSON without changing it?
and local_id is just an auto increment column.

Comment: why do you need local id if you already have id ?

Comment: its server id and in local if i add new "A" row server-id must be 0

Comment: i don't think i got it , you can just put local_id as the position in the array but that would be pointless , can't you remove local_id ?

Comment: yes but as I said this is a big JSON and it consumes a lot of time to put a local id to each item. I cannot remove local id that's my PrimaryKey. if I remove it how can I add a new row to the table?

Comment: use the serverId it should be uniqe aswell the problem is that it starts from 1 ? just do -1 to the serverid

Comment: Parse the elements individually with a stream parser, and insert each element.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce but as I said before that take a lot of time

Comment: Then optimize it.

Comment: How did you end up resolving it in the end?

Comment: not find a way and at last edit my json